# ios ASIHTTPRequest has stopped working when testing on my iPod v4.2.1

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I'm experiencing some really frustrating problems with the asihttprequest. When I run the code in the simulator, everything works fine, but when debugging on my ipod it has suddenly stopped working.

It used to work just fine from the device as well. I have debugged the code, and most of the time the request fails because `secondsSinceLastActivity > [self timeOutSeconds]*1.5` which means there is a timeout. Sometimes the request seems to fail due to a network event, `kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred`?

I try to connect to the server with https. The certificate authority is a trusted one. 
While I was writing this it hit my mind that maybe it's has something to do with the device handling certificates?

And actually when trying to login to gmail or facebook with safari, a dialog saying that "the identity of the server cannot be verified" is displayed. I suppose that is what causes the request to fail? How come my ipod suddenly don't trust any of those certificates? I've googled this instead but haven't found any solution.

I'm not sure this is the correct forum, but can anyone help out with this one? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like there's something odd with your network. Can you describe the network your ipod is connected to in more detail?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I connected to a wi-fi network. It's the same network that I have alwayes connected to without experiencing any problems. I'm not sure whether or not anything has changed with the network, though, it's an office network shared by a lot of people. My mac is connected to the same wi-fi network and connecting from the simulator works okey. Could it still be the network?

Comment: I'd start by figuring out why you're getting problems with gmail and facebook. Is the date/time on the device set correctly?

Comment: Hi @JosephH! Thanks a lot!! The date was set to 1970 something. Changing the date fixed the problem! Thanks for your guidance!

Comment: cool, glad you've got it working! I've posted that as an answer then - feel free to upvote it and accept it (click the 'up arrow' and the 'tick' to the left of the answer)

Comment: I'd love to upvote your answer, but I don't seem to have enough reputation points in order to do that!? I only have 3 you see. Or is there any other way I can give you my votes?

Comment: Ah, you need to get to 15 to be able to upvote. You now have 8 :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by figuring out why you're getting problems with gmail and facebook. Is the date/time on the device set correctly?